# How to store list of installed (paid and unpaid) apps to a log file?

Tags: installation, logging, scripts

I would like to store a list of all paid and unpaid apps in a log file (which I would then upload to Google Drive or FTP to some other server). This way if my phone is lost, stolen, or breaks, I will still have a list of the complete set of apps I had been using, so I will not forget any app I installed. I know Google Play keeps a list of purchased apps in its database, but it does not store the unpurchased ones.

So, is there a script somewhere which will allow me to generate this list (I didn't see anything supporting this functionality in the stock UI, using Android KitKat 4.4.2).

Comment: `library.db` at `/data/data/com.android.vending/databases/` may be what you're looking for. It has some purchase related info about all the apps linked to your Google account. You may pull the file easily if you've root access. Otherwise, backup Play Store app using [tag:adb] and extract the backup using [ABE](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor).

Comment: Yes, but what about the unpaid installed apps. You don't mention these appear in the `library.db` file you mention. Thanks.

Comment: It has all the apps linked to your account irrespective of the pricing status. Pricing details are shown in a column. The unpaid ones would probably show NULL. Just give it a try for once.

Comment: OK, I will download Android Studio so that I can use the `adb shell` command to access my Android device from my PC.

Comment: You may consider: [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474)